# What is the difference between models.ldamodel.LdaModel and models.LdaModel?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

What is the difference between 
`gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(...)` and `gensim.models.LdaModel(...)`?

The [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) use `gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(...)`.

However, [many people](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22models.LdaModel%22&oq=%22models.LdaModel%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.9506j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22models.LdaModel(corpus%22&tbas=0) seem to use `gensim.models.LdaModel(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same. If you look at the source, the [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/__init__.py) in the `models` package has the line:

```
# bring model classes directly into package namespace, to save some typing
from .ldamodel import LdaModel
```

Which basically just makes it so that `gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel` is the same thing as `gensim.models.LdaModel` -- just to save some typing, as helpfully pointed out by the comment.

Comment: Is reading the source code the usual way to proceed when one has a doubt like mine? Is this an efficient way to learn or it takes too much time? (I'm asking in general, not regarding this specific question).

Comment: For simple questions like that, undoubtedly. Given your description I suspected it was exactly that, so confirming it only took 30 seconds. In general I'd say it's always edifying to read other projects' source; unless it's horribly written you'll usually learn a thing or two.